# Ansible/Rackspace - adding multiple nodes to a load balancer

Tags: ansible, load-balancing, rackspace

I'm using Ansible to build multiple nodes and then add them to a load balancer. The issue that arises is that when the second node is being added using the rax_clb_nodes module, I get:

```
TASK: [build-servers | add nodes to load balancer] ************************** 
failed: [myserver-v0-0-1-ord -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true}
msg: Load Balancer '123456' has a status of 'PENDING_UPDATE' and is considered immutable.
changed: [myserver-v0-0-1-ord -> 127.0.0.1]
```

my playbook defines `wait=yes` and `wait_timeout=60` in rax_clb_nodes, so I'm unsure as to why this occurs.

Any insight into a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `rax_clb_nodes` task is being executed in parallel on behalf of each matching host in your inventory, but only one load balancer update can be performed at a time. There are a few approaches to executing it in serial, instead, depending on how your playbooks are organized.

If this task can be easily moved into its own play, use [`serial: 1`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) to execute it on behalf of one host at a time instead:

```
- name: Load balancer membership
  hosts: build-servers
  serial: 1
  tasks:

  - name: Add {{ inventory_hostname }} node to the load balancer
    local_action:
      module: rax_clb_nodes
      address: "{{ rax_addresses.private.0.addr }}"
      port: 443
      state: present
      wait: yes
      wait_timeout: 60
      # ...
```

Unfortunately, `serial` can only be specified on entire plays at a time, not individual tasks. If the task *can't* easily be moved to its own play (for example, if it's within a role or in the midst of an included task list), you can achieve serial execution by a combination of [`run_once`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) and a [`with_items` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops):

```
- name: Add nodes to load balancer
  local_action:
    module: rax_clb_nodes
    address: "{{ hostvars[item].rax_addresses.private.0.addr }}"
    port: 443
    state: present
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 60
    # ...
  run_once: yes
  with_items: "{{ groups['build-servers'] }}"
```